# need help with expressing uniqueness of elements that have the same property

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

In class we were discussing how to translate the sentence *there's a sucker born every minute* .

The teacher showed us two examples

1: which is the wrong way

$\exists x [ sucker(x) \land \forall y(mintue(y) \rightarrow bornAt(x,y))]$

2: the correct way

$\forall y[minute(y) \rightarrow \exists x(sucker(x) \land bornAt(x,y))]$

I wanted to take my understanding further and make a wff that said *there's a sucker that's born every minute and each sucker is also different from each other* without paraphrasing the original sentence.

are any of these the correct way of translating it?

$\forall y[minute(y) \rightarrow \exists x(sucker(x) \land bornAt(x,y) \land \forall z (sucker(z) \rightarrow z \neq x))]$

$\forall y[minute(y) \rightarrow \exists x(sucker(x) \land bornAt(x,y) \land \lnot\exists z (sucker(z) \land z=x))]$

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those express what we want them to.

$\forall z \mathop. (S(z) \to z \neq x)$ is equivalent to $\lnot \exists z \mathop. (S(z) \land z = x)$. Both mean all suckers $z$ are distinct from $x$ (where $x$ is a free variable denoting a sucker). Those statements are false when $z$ and $x$ refer to the same entity.

There are a few properties of suckers and when they're born that you might be talking about by saying that each sucker is different from the others. That *could* be taken to imply that there's a 1:1 mapping between suckers and minutes.

I'm interpreting the sentence as, instead, a consequence of observation that suckers are born at most once and therefore any sucker we find representing some minute can't be a representative of any other minute.

What we want to do is express two different facts about suckers:

1. $\forall y \in M \mathop. \exists x \in S \mathop. B(x, y)$ -- for every minute $y$, there's a sucker born at $y$.
2. $\forall y \in S \mathop. \exists_{\le 1} x \mathop. B(x, y)$ -- every sucker is born at most once.

This is equivalent to:

1. $\forall y \mathop. ( M(y) \to \exists x \mathop. S(x) \land B(x, y))$
2. $\forall y \mathop. (S(y) \to \forall a \forall b \mathop. (B(y, a) \land B(y, b) \to a = b)) $